# How to build `gas`/`as` from binutils to wasm (and support all targets)?

Tags: webassembly, emscripten, binutils

I found some libraries for this purpose but they are old or only support one platform (https://github.com/jandem/diswasm, https://github.com/lal12/wasm-binutils-arm-linux). Is there any working way of doing this now?